# dynamic data binding gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

my datatable formed as follows

```
DataTable dtFinalData = new DataTable();
        //Adding columns for BR details
        dtFinalData.Columns.Add("SupId", typeof(string));
        dtFinalData.Columns.Add("SupName", typeof(string));

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
        int num = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month);

        //--> adding columns for date part (1-31)
        for (int i = 1; i < num + 1; i++)
        {
            dtFinalData.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(bool));
        }
        //<-- adding columns for date part (1-31)


        #endregion

        #region Fill dtFinalData 

        //--> Looping each BR from tblBrList
        foreach (DataRow BrRow in dtBrList.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtFinalData.NewRow();

            int SupId = Convert.ToInt32(BrRow[0]); //retrieve BR ID from dtBrList
            String supName = BrRow[1].ToString(); //retreive Supervisor name from dtBrList

            dr["SupId"] = SupId.ToString();
            dr["SupName"] = supName;

            for (int i = 1; i < num + 1; i++)
            {

                DateTime dtRunningDate = new DateTime(2013, 5, i);

                //select BR_SUP_CODE, 
                DataRow[] drAttendance = dtAttendance.Select("BR_SUP_CODE=" + SupId + " AND SMS_DATE=#" + dtRunningDate + "#", string.Empty);
                if (drAttendance.Length == 1)
                {
                    //CheckBox chkbx = new CheckBox();
                    //chkbx.Checked = true;
                    dr[i.ToString()] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //CheckBox chkbx = new CheckBox();
                    //chkbx.Checked = false;
                    dr[i.ToString()] = false;
                }
            }

            dtFinalData.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        //<-- Looping each BR from tblBrList


        #endregion

        GridView1.DataSource = dtFinalData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Now i want to add checked image in place of true and unchecked image in place of false.how to bind grid view dynamically such that in place of disable check box i want to insert two types of image?

Comment: You want to display a row with only image?? Please show your GridView Markup  too

Comment: want to dynamically create grid column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataTable` part is fine and continue to add the True/False text as per the logic. Now you should handle the `GridView` part. So, define an event handler for the ***[OnRowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound.aspx)*** event of GridView.

In this event only, check for the `Text` property of the cells, and if True/False, clear the cells and add the required image.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  ... />
```

And your event handler will have code as below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
            Image chkImage = new Image();
            chkImage.ImageUrl="~/images/Checked.png";
            Image UnchkImage = new Image();
            UnchkImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/UnChecked.png";

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
         // We will start from 3rd cell because the first 2 cells are 
         // for SupID & SupName, where we don't need to place images
          for (int cellIndex = 2; cellIndex < GridView1.Columns.Count; cells++)
            {
               // Add Checked Image when cell text is true
                if (e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].Text == "true")
                {
                    // clear the cell and add only the image
                    e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].Controls.Clear();
                    e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].Controls.Add(chkImage);
                }
                // Add Unchecked Image when cell text is false
                if (e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].Text == "false")
                {
                    // clear the cell and add only the image
                    e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].Controls.Clear();
                    e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].Controls.Add(unchkImage);
                }
            }
      }
 }
```